# how to keep data comming from Arduino serial written in VB.NET TextBox

Tags: vb.net, arduino-uno

I am sending data from arduino to VB.NET app like rfid number to be shown in TextBox3.Text the data transfered without any problem but after showing in TextBox3.text then removed from textbox and i want it to be in textbox no delete it until I delete it. How can I achieve this?

Arduino Code:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>

#define SS_PIN 10
#define RST_PIN 9
MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);   // Create MFRC522 instance.

void setup() 
{
Serial.begin(9600);   // Initiate a serial communication
SPI.begin();      // Initiate  SPI bus
mfrc522.PCD_Init();   // Initiate MFRC522

}
void loop() 
{
// Look for new cards
if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) 
{
 return;
}
 // Select one of the cards
if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) 
 {
   return;
 }
 //Show UID on serial monitor
  byte letter;
  for (byte i = 0; i < mfrc522.uid.size; i++) 
 {
    Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " ");
    Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX);

  }
   delay(5000);

 }
```

and the code in VB.NET is :

```
  Private Sub TextBox3_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox3.TextChanged
    TextBox2.Text = TextBox3.Text

    Dim str As String = "Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=testdb;Uid=root;Pwd=password"


    Using con As New MySqlConnection(str)


        Dim query As String = "select * from testdatawhere rfid_tag='" & TextBox3.Text & "' 
                               and Date_Operation<= '" & Date.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd ") & "'
                               and Start_Time<= '" & Date.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss ") & "' 
                               and End_Time>= '" & Date.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss ") & "' 
                               or spring_size='' " 'Note:TextBox3 is the RFID number come from RFID arduino
        Dim cm As New MySqlCommand(query, con)


        con.Open()


        Dim rd As MySqlDataReader = cm.ExecuteReader()

        ' Check if any rows exist
        If rd.Read() Then
            If rd.GetString(3) = "small" Then
                SerialPort1.Write("1")

                MessageBox.Show("small")


            ElseIf rd.GetString(3) = "Big" Then
                SerialPort1.Write("2")

                MessageBox.Show("big")

            ElseIf rd.GetString(3) = "Midium" Then
                SerialPort1.Write("3")

                MessageBox.Show("Mid")


            End If

        End If
    End Using
End Sub
```

and the code for serial connection in VB.NET:

```
 Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles   Timer1.Tick
    receivedData = ReceiveSerialData()
    TextBox3.Text = receivedData

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your requirement, but try with TextBox3.Appendtext( receivedData)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was in this code

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles   Timer1.Tick
   receivedData = ReceiveSerialData()
   TextBox3.Text = receivedData

End Sub
```

the correct like this:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles   Timer1.Tick
  receivedData &= ReceiveSerialData()
  TextBox3.Text &= receivedData

End Sub
```

I missed `&` to put it before `=`